# How can I mix a ScrollView and a Grid or Flexview?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm new to nativescript. I just went over the tutorial and was able to make the barebones of an app that has a ScrollView like so:
​

```
<ScrollView (scroll)="onScroll($event)">
    <GridLayout class="m-15" rows="auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto auto">
     <Label class="h3 m-5" height="50" row="0" text="Title 1"></Label>
    <Image class="h3 m-5" row="1" src="https://play.nativescript.org/dist/assets/img/NativeScript_logo.png" height="80" width="80"></Image>
   <Label class="h3 m-5" height="50" row="2" text="Title 3"></Label>
   <Label class="h3 m-5" height="50" row="3" text="Title 4"></Label>
   <Label class="h3 m-5" height="50" row="4" text="Title 5"></Label>
   <Label class="h3 m-5" height="50" row="5" text="Title 6"></Label>
   <Label class="h3 m-5" height="50" row="6" text="Title 7"></Label>
   <Label class="h3 m-5" height="50" row="7" text="Title 8"></Label>
   <Label class="h3 m-5" height="50" row="8" text="Title 9"></Label>
   <Label class="h3 m-5" height="50" row="9" text="Title 10"></Label>
   <Label class="h3 m-5" height="50" row="10" text="Title 10"></Label>
   <Label class="h3 m-5" height="50" row="11" text="Title 11"></Label>
   <Label class="h3 m-5" height="50" row="12" text="Title 12"></Label>
   <Label class="h3 m-5" height="50" row="13" text="Title 13"></Label>
   <Label class="h3 m-5" height="50" row="14" text="Title 14"></Label>
   <Label class="h3 m-5" height="50" row="15" text="Title 15"></Label>
</GridLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

​
However, I'd like to make it so that those elements are in a 2-column grid however I can't figure out how to do it without crashing the app. Can someone help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in rows in GridLayout you are missing comma between `auto` and for two columns you need to add `columns` parameter for example with `asterisks` or `numbers` or `auto`

```
 <GridLayout class="m-15" columns="*,*" rows="auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto, auto">
```

And in elements inside of GridLayout add `col="0"` or `col="1"` based on if it's first or second column

```
<Label class="h3 m-5" height="50" col="0" row="2" text="Title 3"></Label> //third row, first column
<Label class="h3 m-5" height="50" col="1" row="2" text="Title 4"></Label> //third row, second column
```

More in https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/layouts/layout-containers